# Unusual Flash IOError

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, io, adobe, ioerror

I stopped working on a technology I've been developing with Flash for three months. I went back to this project last night and it my Flash app is behaving unusually. URLLoader and Loader instances throw IOErrorEvents when loading from web but not local files. This is happening with all Flash applications on my computer. I have internet access and I can browse the web normally using any browser. I saved my application to use on my MacBook and it work fine. This issue isn't with my code but maybe Flash Player. I have the latest version on my Windows XP pc which is behaving strange. Thank you in advance. Also Flash seems to be working normally on websites meaning they seem to be able to contact their servers and what not. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html  and add your local folders

Comment: I don't know if this helped but the problem is gone. Thank you.